# Show prompt upon exiting for ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an ionic app which requires user to log in to access the content, and currently I'm having a problem: that is the app exits way too easily.

At the moment, any time the user pressing back from the rootPage, the app immediately exits. Upon opening the login page would be shown again and all the session data is wiped.

So I'm having two questions right now:

First, how does ionic detect that the user is trying to leave from the rootPage and exit the app? I want to be able to show a Prompt asking if the user surely want to leave or not when that happen. I've tried showing a prompt when ionViewCanLeave() is called, but then I realized it will get called even when I use NavCtrl to push another page from my rootpage.

Second, how do I save the user profile and session data even after the app is exit on phone? So that the next time the user opens the app they are immediately logged in if they haven't logged out from the previous session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So few things here:

1. **Persisting user data** (such as JWT etc auth tokens) is something you should do during "login" cycle. Just use [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) as solution for that. The way you implement it is described in many guide which you can google for. Example: https://www.joshmorony.com/hybrid-app-developers-dont-store-your-users-passwords/
   But the implementation detail depends on what auth service / approach you have.
2. **For logout** it is normally a good practice to take user to a "login" page after they chose to logout. And if they want to actually close the app on most of the modern platforms it doesn't have to happen by way of removing your rootPage from navstack (like modern iOS closes apps by hitting home then swipe up, Android has its own method).
   So implementation of logout could be the following:

   - side bar menu features "LOGOUT" button
   - user presses it and your logout method performs necessary actions for example:

---

```
logout() {
    this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
    this.storage.remove('sessionData');
    this.inventory.clear();
    if (!this.appIsOnDevice && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
        registrations.forEach(registration => {
          registration.unregister();
        });
      });
    }
    if (this.appIsOnline && this.pushToken !== "") {
      this.revokeFCMToken();
    }
  }
```

If you still want to pursue "prompt" type of approach for leaving the rootPage you can explore option using the nav guard that you tried leveraging "promise":

```
  ionViewCanLeave() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Log out',
        subTitle: 'Are you sure you want to log out?',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'No',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
              reject();
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler: () => {
              alert.dismiss().then(() => {
                resolve();
              });
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();
    });
```

UPDATE: so the above code will also trigger if you just "go to another page" (push in new page), so to make it work the way you wanted you can do the following:

1. have a variable that controls whether logout was requested by user (simple boolean)
2. if user clicks logout button, that points to a logout method - (click) = "logout()", make sure such method updates the boolean:

   logout() {
       // change the flag for user logout event:
       this.logoutRequested = true;
       // the rest of logout logic:
     }
3. Now in the nav guard method you can simply check for this boolean state

### Example

```
ionViewCanLeave() {
        // here we add this check - if logout is not requested - the page is free to leave (as in case where you push in new page into view:
        if (!this.logoutRequested) return true;
        // if that condition is not met and logoutRequested is true we proceed with modal via promise, but before that we can already reset flag:
        this.logoutRequested = false;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Log out',
            subTitle: 'Are you sure you want to log out?',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'No',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                  reject();
                }
              },
              {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: () => {
                  alert.dismiss().then(() => {
                    resolve();
                  });
                }
              }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So to store user data, i just need to use Ionic Storage, no prob. But I don't think modifying ionViewCanLeave can get me what I want cause as I stated above, the prompt will show up even when navctrl is pushing another page from the rootpage.

Comment: let me update my answer with some suggestion re this question

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I inject this snipppet of code into my app module to achieve what I want

```
  this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    if (this.nav.canGoBack()) {
      this.nav.pop();
    } else {
      this.promptExit();
    }
  })

  private promptExit() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Exit?',
      message: 'Do you want to exit My App?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Exit',
          handler: () => {
            // Insert whatever you need to do before exiting here
            ...
            this.platform.exitApp())
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```